# How to match rownames and colnames of a matrix to a column in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a text file that has a column called **ID** with a values E.g. A B C

```
variant_id gene tss_distance ma_samples ma_count  ID      
1  chr1 ENSG      80       68       78    A
2  chr1 ENSG      80       395      486   B
3  chr1 ENSG      80       167      183   C
```

I have a matrix that is square, so has 5000 x 5000. The rownames = colnames.
(My matrix column and row names match). The rownames and colnames also match **some** IDs in the ID column in the dataframe. The matrix may contain extra IDs not found in the dataframe.

```
    [A][B][C][D]  
[A] value1 value2 value3 value4
[B] value5 value6 value7 value8 
[C] value9 value10 value11 value12
[D] value13 value14 value15 value16
```

I want the matrix rownames and colnames to exactly match the ID column in the dataframe.

Matrix should be (for example):
Notice how the D does not appear because D is missing in the dataframe.

```
   [A][B][C]  
[A] value1 value2 value3 value4
[B] value9 value10 value11 value12
[C] value13 value14 value15 value16
```

The problem with using the below command is it just filters the rows, I need the col and rows to be removed if not found in the dataframe, so the matrix is still a square. The rownames and colnames of the final matrix should exactly match the ID column in the dataframe.

```
matrix <- matrix[row.names(matrix)%in%dataframe$ID,]
```

The rownames must = the colnames of the matrix and therefore be a square. This must be true:

```
identical(rownames(matrix),colnames(matrix))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `match` twice.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(ID = LETTERS[1:3])
mat <- matrix(1:16, ncol = 4, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:4], LETTERS[1:4]))

i_row <- match(df1$ID, rownames(mat))
i_col <- match(df1$ID, colnames(mat))
mat[i_row, i_col]
#>   A B  C
#> A 1 5  9
#> B 2 6 10
#> C 3 7 11
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

If there are column and row names not present in `df1$ID`, then `intersect` is a solution.

```r
i_row <- intersect(df1$ID, rownames(mat))
i_col <- intersect(df1$ID, colnames(mat))
mat[i_row, i_col]
#>   A B  C
#> A 1 5  9
#> B 2 6 10
#> C 3 7 11
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @HKJ3 If all values in column `ID` are col and row names of the matrix then that cannot happen. Can you post sample data in `dput` format? If so, please edit *the question*  with the output of `dput(df$ID)` and of `dput(mat)`. Or, if they are too big, with a subset of those data sets.

Comment: Yes you are right. When I do df$ID %in% rownames(matrix). I get some false. Which is a problem.Is there a way in which I can discard the IDs that are false in the dataframe too. The end outcome should still be the same i.e Matrix rownames and colnames match the ID column.

Comment: @HKJ3 Instead of `match` or `%in%`, maybe to give `intersect` a try? Note that generally `intersect` is not the 1st choice due to its slow execution, `match` is much faster. But to match a few colnames and row names this is probably not important. See the edit.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will take out the IDs out the data-frame that aren't in the matrix and retry! Intersect doesn't maintain the square structure of the matrix.